# What kind of model is used by 20 Questions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-mining

Which kind of machine learning concept / model is used in [20 Questions](http://www.20q.net)?
Is this kind of thing best solved by a neural network?
Where I can read something about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a large [collaboratively edited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_intelligence) database of conditional branches basically, but it is probably not so reliable unless humans review/correct its collection (not sure how much that is done). it uses some principles similar to [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search). it is also similar to [expert systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) except that its modifiable.

basically the answers to the questions serve as a "unique address" of the different objects in memory ie it can probably be modelled largely as a huge [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). it also has some rough similarity to a famous CS project called [Cyc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyc), part of the [Symbolic AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence#Symbolic) school of thought, that attempted to categorize all human knowledge. 20Q has a [FAQ here](http://www.20q.net/faq.html). another somewhat related/more recent technology in this area is [rules engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_engine).

as an example/single random sample of its reliability/coverage, picked "tv" as the object & it basically failed. also some of the guesses dont really seem to make sense, hence possibly a poor quality of "samples" collected from random web users who dont have much incentive to provide high quality responses (and might amuse themselves by not doing so).

```
You won!
Q30.  I am guessing that it is a Pikachu (Pokemon character)?
Right, Wrong, Close 
29.     I guessed that it was a record (before CD's)? Wrong.
28.     Is it heavy? No.
27.     I guessed that it was a cartoon? Wrong.
26.     Do you make something with it? No.
25.     Is it smaller than a loaf of bread? No.
24.     Do you use it in cooking? No.
23.     I guessed that it was a model train? Wrong.
22.     Does it use electricity? Yes.
21.     Can it be played? No.
20.     I guessed that it was a hairdryer? Wrong.
19.     Was it used over 100 years ago? No.
18.     I guessed that it was an autoharp? Wrong.
17.     Do you use it in your home? Yes.
16.     Does it have a horn? No.
15.     Is it worth a lot of money? No.
14.     Is it larger than a pound of butter? Yes.
13.     Would you use it in the dark? No.
12.     Is it straight? No.
11.     Do you need batteries to use it? No.
10.     Can you put something into it? No.
9.      Is it larger than a microwave oven (or bread box)? No.
8.      Do you use it at work? No.
7.      Does it ring? No.
6.      Is it a root vegetable? No.
5.      Does it have buttons? Yes.
4.      Does it play music? Sometimes.
3.      Does it make noise? Yes.
2.      Is it used for entertainment? Yes.
1.      It is classified as Other.
```

Comment: How could be handled answer like sometimes in this kind of decision tree?

Comment: another related system, see also [IBM watson/jeopardy computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_(computer))

Answer (score 3):

You just play once with it, observe it, and you have the model. Try
something non obvious, or simply cheat with answers.

**The game**: you think of something, and 20Q asks questions to find what
it is.

They just collect the answers from the players.  They have a
collection of questions that are supposed to discriminate solutions.
They ask questions to users, who chooses among 7 possible answers. Recall that with just 20 yes/no answers, you can discriminate 1 million different objects. And their questions have more answers that just two.
The combinatorics of the answers will identify the right "something"to
be guessed in the available collection. If the thing they are supposed
to identify has not appeared before, they do not find it, recognize
that they lost, ans ask what it is.  Then it goes into the database,
with all the user's answers to identify it the next time.

So they fail, but not twice on the same "something/someone/somewhere"
to be guessed.  Unless users give wrong answers to questions (the
first time, or afterwards ...?).

It is probably slightly subtler, but I doubt it has much artificial
intelligence, neural network or otherwise.  A most elementary and
simplistic form of machine learning, if one dares use the expression
for it.

This is all pure guesswork from what I observed. No idea where you
could read about it. Not sure there is anything worth reading anyway.